# targeting specific element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a jquery nav-bar , that will show what you will view when you hover over one of the links:

[image: not much styling , but when u hover over the yellow one it should say link 1 maybe , green link 2 and so on]

the html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function  () {
   $('a span').hide();
       $('li a').hover(
         function(){
           //the right span should show
        },
         function(){
           // the same span should hide
        }
    );
 });
```

So i want to grab the first span if the first item is being hovered , and so on. I thought of a solution to make many functions but that wouldn't be very helpful , and yeah i am a jquery noob.

Comment: Inside each of the functions you pass to the `hover()` method you can use `$(this)` to refer to the currently hovered element.

Comment: The best approach is to add css rule to `a span` - `display: none`. In this case span will be hidden by default and you avoid blinking

Comment: i wanted to do it with jquery , i already now how to do that with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem to be as simple as:

```
$('li a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).find('span').toggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

Comment: what does " e.which == 'mouseenter' " do ?

Comment: @aleksXPO `e.which == 'mouseenter'` doesn't do anything, @billyonecan is right, but `e.type == 'mouseenter'` creates a boolean value which is then passed to the `.toggle()` function. [jQuery .toggle docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

Comment: @billy: thanks for the catch! That's certainly what I *meant* to type, but somehow, clearly, my fingers had other ideas...

Comment: @DavidThomas I had no doubt that it was :p Neat solution, never knew you could pass a bool to `toggle()`

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to trigger the event on the anchor, as you're hiding the span, and therefore the anchor has nothing inside of it, you could bind the handler to the `li` element:

```
 $('li').hover(
      function(){
        $(this).find('span').show();
     },
      function(){
        $(this).find('span').hide();
     }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks :) this is probably the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the current element you need to use $(this). See the following:

```
$('li a').hover(
    function () {
      $(this).find('span').show()
    },
    function () {
      $(this).find('span').hide()
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show a color when you hover over it. Try the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/uCPL7/)

```
$('li a').mouseenter(
     function(){
    $(this).show().css({'background' : 'red'});
}).mouseout(function(){
$(this).css({'background' : ''});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code:

```
$('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```